# Length with condition

Tags: twig

I know twig can count elements of an array using `{{ array|length}}`, but is there a way to combine this feature with an `if`  or `where` statement?

Something like `{{ array|length|array.key is null }}`, where it would count all the instances where `key` is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`filter`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html) filter should help you achieve this.

Something like

```
{% set array = [null, 42, null, null, 42] %}

{{ array | filter(item => item is null) | length }}
```

Outputs `3`

---

And so if I understand your data structure correctly:

```
{% set array = [{key:  null}, {key:  42}, {key: null}, {key: null}, {key: 
 42}] %}

{{ array | filter(item => item.key is null) | length }}
```